# The expected number of sunny days in a year

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, markov-chains

Suppose there are two types of weathers. Sunny and Rainy. 
The probability that a sunny day is followed by a sunny day is 70% and followed by a rainy day is 30%.  
The probability that a rainy day is followed by a rainy day is 60% and followed by a sunny day is 40%.  
In a year (365 days), how many days do we expect to be sunny?

Based on the question above, I only get the transition matrix
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.7 & 0.3\\
0.4 & 0.6 
\end{bmatrix}
$
May I ask how do I calculate the expected number of sunny days in a year?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for the "long run" probability that it is sunny, or alternatively looking for an "equilibrium vector" (such that $vP=v$ since this matrix is regular). The most basic way (but not the most efficient) method of finding this is just raising it to an incredibly huge power, as an approximation - the rows typically (but not always, I think it needs to be irreducible & aperiodic?) become $v$ in the limit. You can also justify it as $P^T v^T = v^T$, so it is (the transpose of) an eigenvector of $P^T$ tied to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. Other methods probably exist, too.

Comment: Everyday is dark if you ask me.

Comment: Let $\psi$ be the long term probability that it is sunny on a fixed day.  Now compute the probability that it is sunny on the next day and use the assumption that $\psi $ is constant.

Comment: Should note:  clearly the calculation I described relies on the assumption that the long term probability exists.  That is, it assumes existence and then computes the value.  A priori it is possible that there is no such probability.  If that issue is a concern, the Markov method is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expanding on what the comments said. Let $P$ be the ptm. What you want to find is $(P^T)^{365}\pmatrix{1\\0}$

The idea is that overall long enough timespans (ex:365 days) we reach a stationary probability distribution $v$ since:

$(P^T)^{364} \pmatrix{1\\0} \approxeq (P^T)^{365}\pmatrix{1\\0}$. So let $v$ be the long run dist $(P^T)^{364}\pmatrix{1\\0}$ to get that $P^Tv = v$. So let $v = (v_1, v_2)$.

This gives us three equations:

$v_1 + v_2 = 1$

$0.7v_1 + 0.4v_2 = v_1$

$0.3v_1 + 0.6v_2 = v_2$

which gives us that $v_1 = 4/7$ and $v_2 = 3/7$

Answer (score 1):

Taking that the steady state probability exists, let these probabilitie be **s** for sunny and **r** for rainy, then one more iteration won't change these probabiliies, hence

$s*0.7 + r*0.4 = s$

$s*0.3 + r*0.6 = r$

$s+r=1$

which yields $s = \frac47, r = \frac37$

The required answer $=\frac47\times 365$